# Laravel external class files

Tags: php, laravel, class, namespaces

I have a file that i put in `app\Classes\myVendor\dev_client_api.php`. This file has a class in it:

```
class someClass{
   //stuff
}
```

I want to use this class in a controller.

In my controller I have done the following:

```
namespace App\Classes\myVendor;
use dev_client_api;

class myController extends Controller
{
    ///stuff
    public function processData(Request $request){
       $client = new someClass($vars);
    }
}
```

When i execute this page I get:

> Class 'App\Classes\myVendor\Controller' not found

I have to admit I am not sure what exactly I am doing.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Your folder seem to be "classes" instead of "Classes" as you specified in the namespace, is this a post typo? check that out.

Comment: That was a typo in SO.  sorry bout that

Comment: Is your controller inside that folder? if not, why do you add the namespace there? that namespace (`namespace App\Classes\myVendor;`) should be in the `dev_client_api.php` and not in the Controller. Thats why it isn't finding the base Controller that you are extending (I assume this based in your error).

Comment: I suggest reading the PHP [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). You might also want to read up on the Laravel documentation. Following common coding conventions prevents mistakes like this.

Comment: How many classes do you have in `dev_client_api.php`?

Comment: just one @RossWilson

Comment: ...and that class is called `someClass`?

Comment: it is a vendor specific class name.  I changed the name to someClass. Sentry solved my issue below.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Controllers are in Laravel's default `App\Http\Controller` directory.

```
namespace App\Classes\myVendor;

class someClass {
   //stuff
}
```

---

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Classes\myVendor\someClass;

class myController extends Controller
{
    ///stuff
    public function processData(Request $request){
       $client = new someClass($vars);
    }
}
```